# Winston Not working on Windows 8 for plotting in Julia

Tags: julia

I downloaded Julia and then used Pkg.add("Winston"). I then proceeded to try and make a plot:

```
    using Winston
    x = rand(100)
    y = [1:100]
    plot(x,y)
```

but everytime I tried to make a plot I got:

```
    FramedPlot(...)
```

I figured out that the problem was the Tk package but I could not fix the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is how I fixed the problem on windows 8. I figured out that Tk was the issue and it was trying to link to one set of dlls for Tcl (I think it was Tcl 8.6) which it found in my anaconda python directory and then it was linking to the proper dll's for Tk (8.5). So to fix the problem I went into the .julia folder (under C://Users/Myusername//.julia//v0.3//Tk//deps//build.jl) and opened the build.jl using notepad.

I then went to the part of the code for tcl and tk library dependencies and deleted anything that had 8.6 (or 86) in the name such as "tcl86t". NOTE: I had to do this for both the tcl and tk dependencies!

Once I did this I restarted Julia and used

```
    Pkg.build("Tk")
```

And Voila I had it working. I hope this helps anyone else that is going through the same headache that I was, it was really annoying me because everything worked fine on my Ubuntu computer but not my windows one.